# Couchdb Update queries read arrays as strings?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I have made updateHandler on cloudant(couchdb) as

```
"_id": "_design/updateValues",
 "updates": {
   "change": function(doc, req) {
         var id = req.query.id;
         var section = req.query.section;
         if(section[0]==something) {    
              //update values
         }
```

`req.query.section` is an array that has values like ["mango", "apple", "banana"].
When I am trying to read the query in the database as section[0], instead of getting mango(1st element in the array) I am getting '[' which is the first character.

I have double checked the array on my node server, and it works totally fine there. It's only on the database side that is acting a bit weird.

What would be causing this? How can I access different 'elements' in the array and not characters?

Comment: How do you know `req.query.section` should be an array? How is your URL formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `req.query.section` is a string with encoded JSON. Try making it an array using the JSON object, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse.